# Is there a way to exclude a database from mongodump

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, backup, mongodump

I am using **mongodump** for daily backups.
In my database server i have many DBs, I want to exclude huge DB from dumping.
e.g : dump all DBs except '*Db_name*', something like : mongoump --out /data/backup *--excludeDatabase='name_of_db'*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exclude the databases for [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/index.html) command still [in a feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-22) accepted state. I would suggest writing a script to individually backup required databases and using [excludeCollectionsWithPrefix](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-excludecollectionswithprefix) if you can identify a pattern to exclude the collections

Comment: I don't find any option allow to ignore database, so i wrote a simple **bash script** that check all database and there size, and when dumping i skip large Database.

Comment: Yes, that the best option available now.